# UICollectionView Scroll particular column horizontally

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, collectionview

I am using a `UIColectionView` in my app. I am using line layout that scroll column horizontally. I have multiple columns. I want columns that goes out of screen to be scrollable horizontally.

I have to make netflix or default ipad AppStore app like design.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how a collection view works.

You will have to use a table view with each cell containing a scroll view with horizontal scroll enabled and all the content for that cell.